# How can I prevent `curl` from printing a table with progress information?

Tags: ssh, curl

From 16.04 command line:

```
$ ssh user@gatorback.asuscomm.com "curl http://192.168.8.5/tstat"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0{"temp":68.00,"tmode":2,"fmode":0,"override":0,"hold":0,"t_cool":82.00,"program_mode":1,"tstate":0,"fstate":0,"time":{"day":5,"hour":1100   164    0   164    0     0    101      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--   101
```

Why is the speed table returned and how can this be surpressed?

Comment: Did you try `man curl`?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli  Thanks for the nudge: once I understood the nomenclature 'Progress Meter` I could then quickly Google the silencing syntax

Answer (score 6):

The [Progress Meter](https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline/cmdline-progressmeter) can be silenced with the `-s / --silent` option:

```bsh
ssh user@gatorback.asuscomm.com "curl -s http://192.168.8.5/tstat"
# or
ssh user@gatorback.asuscomm.com "curl --silent http://192.168.8.5/tstat"
```